# Picture of blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Can anyone point me to the picture I saw somewhere but can not find it anymore where blockchain is represented as a line of blocks chained together. There was a locker on each little block, and each block was chained to the next one.
The blocks were forming something like a line/queue of blocks
I'm googling for an hour now and can not find it anymore

**UPDATE 1**

Here is a sketch of what I had in mind.
I'm sure I saw it somewhere but it might have been in a video about blockchain.

[image]

And then the block chain was like a very long (infinite) line of blocks

[image]

Comment: Like this? http://spectrum.ieee.org/img/06Bitcoin-1338412974774.jpg I think you're going to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Thanks @NickODell like the fragment in the top right corner where the blocks are chained but with the "real chain" - I want to use it to explain the nature of the block chain to layman so no hashes signatures etc 
The picture with real chain will do ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the free e-book [*Mastering Bitcoin*](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch07.html#merkle_trees) by Andreas Antonopoulos:

[image: Blokchain from «Mastering Bitcoin»]

Comment: Thanks @Geremia this one is very nice :-) but not exactly what I'm looking for. See the update I've sketched the one I was thinking about.